# TagLib is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have installed TagLib via Package Manager Console in Visual Studio 2017, but when I attempt to use "Using TagLib" it fetches an error as can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A2xc.png NuGet installation page can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSBLh.png and TagLib is installed. I am also unable to call for any TagLib functions.

Comment: Are you sure you added the nugget reference to the same project where your code is? C# is case sensitive, can you confirm that you're trying to use it with `using TagLib;` ?

Comment: If you are talking about the `using TagLib;` yes I've added that.
It shows the error in the picture ive linked in the post